# What is the "metadata operation failed" VS2008 linker error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I have a big project that was first created in Borland C++ 6.

We're porting the program gradually to VS2008. There are many projects, which all compile to .lib, and I'm trying to build the exe of the test project for a set of projects.

After fixing the compiler errors, I got this crazy linker error:

*1>av_geos_core_domain.lib(GerTamMolde.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (PtoGrad): (0x02000045).*

It appears 4 other times with different classes. The .obj listed are classes (GerTamMolde and PtoGrad).

I tried cleaning and building the solution again many times but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried searching for duplicated symbols? In my opinion PtoGrad is defined in two or more places, perhaps in different .lib, making the symbol resolving when building the .exe crash.